# React Native, setInterval stopped when activity is on pause

Tags: javascript, timer, react-native

I would to create a **timer** in my App. I created a timer as:

```js
var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
var rest = 90;
timer.innerHTML = rest + 's';
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  if(rest <= 0){
    clearInterval(interval);
   }else{
     rest -= 1;
    timer.innerHTML = rest + 's';
  }
  
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id='timer'></div>
```

But, when the user leaves my app **(NOT KILL, JUST LEAVE)** and go to any other app, the timer stops working.

And when he comes back to my app, the timer starts working.

Comment: 2023: check out https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services "foreground service". It'll save you so much time as we developers just want to run code when the app isn't shown but no one mentions this. For react-native, I used notifee. I'll update my blog post in the future.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I have use a trick.

```
var that = this;
  for(var i = 1; i <= that.state.restSec; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
      //do your stuff here
    }, i * 1000);
  }
```

When you come back timeouts are updated like they have worked during the "onpause" :).

Answer (score 4):

This question is a copy to the following:

[How can I run background tasks in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376690/how-can-i-run-background-tasks-in-react-native)

The following answer is written:
Currently, there is, unfortunately, no support for background tasks of any kind. The feature you are referring to would be a background timer. Such a timer is  [this product plain](https://productpains.com/post/react-native/background-timer-execution) (a feature request) for react native, you may upvote it to show an increased demand for this feature.

(There is no update yet. As far as i know)

Comment: For me background task could be use when your application is killed. In my case is I just want the timer not stopped when the user just lock his phone.

Comment: The only option i see for you to make your 'background-task' possible is to completely implement it native. But therefore i have not the experience to give u the right answer. I just found 2 links wich i will share to you and maybe they help you:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html