# Can React-Native run a background task in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native, healthkit

**Desired spec:** 
React Native app queries HealthKit data and then POSTs to DB

Building a React-Native app that will query a user's HealthKit data intermittently.

Aware that you can't interact with HealthKit while the phone is unlocked.

This thread [How can I run background tasks in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376690/how-can-i-run-background-tasks-in-react-native) tells me that such functionality isn't possible currently with RN.

However, this is in the context of starting a background-timer. I'd like the app to perform the following steps

1. Query HealthKit data for # of steps
2. POST data to DB

**Questions**

1. Is this possible with React Native without writing some kind of native bridge? (Swift seems to have this capability somehow)
2. If not possible without writing a bridge, what about accessing the native pedometer?