# Waking up an app on IOS with react-native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to create an Alarm Clock app for IOS and Android. I am having hard time figuring out how to wake up the app at a specific time on both platforms. I found `react-native-app-launcher` which should work for android, but not IOS.

Is there any NativeModule or library for that ?

Comment: I think you'll find the answer in the discussion of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376690/how-can-i-run-background-tasks-in-react-native

Comment: There is no support for launching an app at a specific time in iOS. You can schedule a local notification for delivery at a specific time and if the user taps the notification then it will launch your app.