# React Native background timer never stops

Tags: javascript, react-native, timer

I'm building an app that has a timer to request geolocation while the timer is active. For a timer I'm using [react-native-background-timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer). Which is kind of working, but not exactly as I want.

With this piece of code:

```
BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(() => { 
    console.log('tic');
},  
1000);
```

the timer is stopping when the app is in the background. While with this piece of code:

```
const intervalId = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {
    console.log('tic');
}, 1000);
```

it runs constantly even in the background, but I'm not able to stop it. When I run `BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(intervalId);`, the timer still runs. Even when I leave the screen and go back to my Home screen, the timer still ticks and never stops. This is not ideal, because I need timer to run for a few minutes and then stop.

I set the timer to 1 second to update time left on the screen. I was thinking about setting a timer once for 6 minutes, but then how do I update the state every second? Making 2 timers for this feels like a bad practise, even though it would work.

So to make it more clear, the user suppose to engage in certain activity like walking for a few minutes. So I can't let the timer to stop when user is answering a call or opened a music app to switch music or something else. Timer still needs to run and I need to measure the number of steps and distance with geolocation. It need to work flawlessly even if user opened another app, forgot about my app, and it would still run for the remaining time, then made a record to the database and stopped.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try the following code snippet,
works both on android and ios

```
import { DeviceEventEmitter, NativeAppEventEmitter, Platform } from 'react-native';
import _BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer';

const EventEmitter = Platform.select({
    ios: () => NativeAppEventEmitter,
    android: () => DeviceEventEmitter,
})();

class BackgroundTimer {
    static setInterval(callback, delay) {
        _BackgroundTimer.start();
        this.backgroundListener = EventEmitter.addListener("backgroundTimer", () => {
            this.backgroundTimer = _BackgroundTimer.setInterval(callback, delay);
        });
        return this.backgroundListener;
    }

    static clearInterval(timer) {
        if (timer) timer.remove();
        if (this.backgroundTimer)
            _BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(this.backgroundTimer);
        _BackgroundTimer.stop();
    }
}

export default BackgroundTimer;
```

**Usage**

```
const timer = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(callback, 1000);
BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(timer)
```

Comment: You have nicely set the code, but still I am confuse that what `BackgroundTimer` in Usage is when you imported `_BackgroundTimer` from plugin ?

Comment: Have you used `_BackgroundTimer.setInterval` @KirankumarDafda?

Comment: Yes, I am using but when its not working when app is in background but working fine when is in foreground

Comment: That's what was happened with me, after reading the docs https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer#usage-ios.
I used the `start`, `stop` approach and triggered the `backgroundTimer` which was implemented in `_BackgroundTimer` and it worked like a charm being app is in background

When app is in foreground then you don't need to implement the above solution, `setInterval` & `clearInterval` apis will do the job for you

Comment: I am trying the same way written here, but still not getting desire response. Tried other things and edit too, but still fails

Comment: which version you are using right now? gist for my implementation https://gist.github.com/vemarav/2cf978e5bde669f7d69ce20e30c11bc3

Comment: Hey, thanks for help but I am still not able to complete it, will try with changing version and update you if whatever completes the req., Thanks again

Comment: I mean when use even `app died` force close the app??

Comment: @Muhammad wont work when app died and all associated background tasks get killed.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I got the following error when using @Aravind Vemula's answer.
When calling `BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(timer);` the following error appears:

> timer.remove is not a function

That's why I modified the code slightly.

```
// parameter removed
static clearInterval() {
    // ADD this if statement 
    if (this.backgroundListener){ 
        this.backgroundListener.remove();
    }
    if (this.backgroundTimer)
        _BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(this.backgroundTimer);
    _BackgroundTimer.stop();
}
```

The above code checks if a backgroundlistener is registered. If yes it removes all listeners and especially our backgroundTimer.

**Usage**:

```
BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(); // removed parameter
```

After my change, everything is working fine on iOS 14.3.

Answer (score 1):

@Aravind Vemula's answer working properly. But if user open the app from the background and timer code is added in background handler then when you stop the timer it is not working. So following changes you need to make in both the methods.

```
static setInterval(callback, delay) {
    if (!this.backgroundListener && !this.locationTimer) {
      _BackgroundTimer.start();
      this.backgroundListener = EventEmitter.addListener('backgroundTimer', () => {
        this.locationTimer = _BackgroundTimer.setInterval(callback, delay);
      });
      return this.locationTimer;
    }
  }

  static clearInterval() {
    if (this.backgroundListener) {
      this.backgroundListener.remove();
    }
    if (this.locationTimer) {
      _BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(this.locationTimer);
    }
    this.backgroundListener = false;
    this.locationTimer = false;
    _BackgroundTimer.stop();
    _BackgroundTimer.start();
  }
```