# React Native: setTimeout not working when app is backgrounded

Tags: react-native, settimeout

In React Native, when `setTimeout` is used to schedule execution of callback and then app is backgrounded, callback is never executed.

Why is that?

I did find [several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51997908/676571) [secondary](https://forums.expo.dev/t/react-native-app-in-background-w-settimeout-and-push-notification/14605) [sources](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) which mention this behavior but no comprehensive docs.

Answer (score -1):

Use the AppState event listener provided by react-native :-

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change", nextAppState => 
  {
      if (
        appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) 
      ) {
         setTimeout(()=>{
          // your callback function
         },1000)
      }

    
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Here's the link to docs - https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate

Comment: Thanks for the link, but text there does not mention that there are changes in behavior of timers when app is in bacgtround.