# Location not updating on server when app enters stationary when app is in background or is closed using mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation

Tags: android, react-native, background, geolocation

Location updates correctly when app is in foreground or when sent to background while user is moving but if app goes into stationary region while app is closed or is background location stops to update. Even if I travel distance once app goes to stationary region from background or terminate state it does not exit stationary region and stops updating location on server.

**Environment:**

```
React Native version: 0.59.9
Plugin version: 0.6.3
Platform: Android
OS version: 7
Device manufacturer and model: Redmi Note 4
```

**Plugin configuration options:**

```
BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
      desiredAccuracy: 10,
      stationaryRadius: 10,
      distanceFilter: 5,
      notificationTitle: 'Background Tracking',
      notificationText: 'Enabled',
      debug: true,
      startOnBoot: true,
      stopOnTerminate: false,
      locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.DISTANCE_FILTER_PROVIDER,
      interval: 5000,
      url: url,
      syncUrl: url,
      httpHeaders: {
        ...this.props.headers
      },
      postTemplate: {
        lat: '@latitude',
        long: '@longitude',
        id: id // you can also add your own properties`
      }
    })
```

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue? If yes can you share the solution ?

Comment: Same issue here until now.

Comment: Any solution arrived for this issue? Facing a similar issue.

Comment: @Logunath, 
No, I am still facing the same issue

Comment: @coffee Okay, It seems the library is not updated recently. We need to migrate to the expo location package.

Comment: but I am not using expo can I use its location package. @Logunath

Comment: Yes, you can, follow the bare react-native instructions.